# Nexus emulator does not work in eclipse - I get a black screen with emulator nav keys

Tags: android-emulator

when I choose `Run As->Android Application` In eclipse, I get the following message:

```
[2013-12-12 12:54:30 - Emulator] extension WGL_ARB_make_current_read was not found
[2013-12-12 12:54:30 - Emulator] could not load func glBindBuffer
[2013-12-12 12:54:30 - Emulator] could not load func glBlendEquationSeparate
[2013-12-12 12:54:30 - Emulator] could not load func glBufferData
[2013-12-12 12:54:30 - Emulator] could not load func glBufferSubData
[2013-12-12 12:54:30 - Emulator] could not load func glDeleteBuffers
...
```

[image]

When I decrease memory for my virtual device and then run the app, I can see the emulator, but a black screen instead of showing the output. Is there any workaround for it?
NB: I use nexus 7 emulator.

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The error you've included indicates that the graphics driver on your desktop machine doesn't support the GL extensions that the emulator needs. Turn off **Use host GPU** in the AVD settings.

Without using the host GPU, the emulator will run very slowly, especially if the app you're using is graphics-heavy. The emulator will take several minutes to start Android. You may wish to consider upgrading the graphics card in your computer, to allow it to take advantage of this feature.

Comment: **Use host GPU** has been disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the work-arounds mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33930#c27)

- Disable OpenGLES emulation support by renaming \tools\lib\libOpenglRender.dll to libOpenglRender.dll.disabled. Or,
- Reduce the amount of memory used by the emulator. Try 900MB, if that doesn't work, try 800MB, if that doesn't work, try 700MB, you get the idea.
- Manually set the resolution of your AVD instead of choosing a template like WX800 or WX720

Comment: I renamed it to **libOpenglRender.dll.disabled** and set the ram to 128 MB but no success. And how to set the resolution?